# Limit involving cube root

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate: $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{x}$ ($\root3 \of{x+1}$ - $ \root3 \of{x-1})$

I tried to multip. by the conjugate, but it just turned into a big mess with nowhere to go

Comment: Use $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3$.

Comment: Or you could use the MVT: $(x+1)^{1/3}- (x-1)^{1/3} = (1/3)(c_x)^{-2/3}\cdot 2.$ That's on the order of $x^{-2/3}.$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$$\root3 \of{x+1} - \root3 \of{x-1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+ \sqrt[3]{x^2-1}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+ \sqrt[3]{x^2-1}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}}$$